# Which coding strategies exist to handle opengl texture size limit?

Tags: opengl, texture, data-structure

I recently hit the roof for maximum texture size for my opengl implementation (GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE contains $3379$) when I wanted to create a texture for a 4k resolution video frame ($3840 \times 2160$).

This made me think about various ways to circumvent the problem that $3840>3379$.

I have used TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, and I suppose one way would be to create such an array with sizes divided by two. In my case 4 slices of $1920\times 1080$ which then get to represent one "quadrant" each. Like a "block-matrix", so to speak.

I was thinking maybe there exist other, better solutions of how to address this.

Comment: I would do it the same way. Saving as `TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` allows you to use layered rendering. To do this, you can use the geometry shader to duplicate the edited faces and rasterize them in all texture quadrants, using only one drawing call. This is especially useful if the vertex calculations are very computationally intensive. When using different textures, you would have to either cache the calculation (transform feedback buffer or shader storage buffer) or calculate it accordingly multiple times (per texture once).

Comment: 3379 is very small for modern hardware, perhaps consider changing out the hardware itself.

Comment: or check if you have installed the newest driver

Comment: @pmw1234 yes I am aware. It is an old card from.. almost 10 years ago, I think. Given how much interest I have for software development and graphics in general you are definitely right, but the current price situation on the GPU market is not very attractive.

Comment: @Thomas this seems very interesting! Feel free to make an answer. I would gladly upvote.

Comment: @mathreadler: "*GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE contains 3379*" No, it does not. That's the value of the *enumerator* (0x0D33), not the value of your implementation's maximum texture size. You have to use `glGetIntegerv` with that enumerator to get the *actual* maximum texture size.

Comment: Of course! you are right Nicol. This makes a lot more sense. A power of 2: 16384

Comment: With a hardware that old, you should check if layered rendering is supported before starting implementing it...

Comment: As Nicol pointed out, I needed to call an API function to get the true value which was 16384 -- a bit more reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a correction:

> GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE contains 3379

No, it does not. That is the value of the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` *enumerator* (0x0D33). The actual implementation-defined maximum size is queried with `glGetIntegerv` *using* that enumerator.

---

As for how to render to a conceptual image larger than the size of the texture you can create... you're just going to have to render the scene several times, with different viewports to different images. You can employ [layered rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering) with array textures to shift viewports between the layers. And you should do different frustum culling for the different layers (so you're not rendering the exact same scene multiple times). But that's about it.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. That it needs to actually go get the value from somewhere and not just expect it to be there waiting. Thank you Nicol.